# -[NSResponder showContextHelp:] example

Tags: cocoa, nsresponder

I'm curious with the method -showContextHelp: in NSResponder.

The documentation states:

> Implemented by subclasses to invoke the help system, displaying information relevant to the receiver and its current state.

How and when is this method called? Can't seem to find anymore information on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-showContextHelp:` and related methods on `NSResponder` are no longer relevant because they were used to respond to [Help key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help_key) events on older Apple keyboards. The Help key no longer exists on any of Apple's keyboards as of 2007.

However, if you're still interested in understanding its purpose, Peter Hosey wrote a [great article](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2011-06-14/help-key-made-useful) on `NSResponder`'s help related functionality.